# Firefox bug: click event lost if resize:vertical set on focus

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Problem: Firefox loses the first click event when a textarea has the following CSS:

```
textarea:focus {
    resize: vertical;
}
```

See demo: http://jsbin.com/wuxomaneba/edit?html,css,output

The solution to this is simple - remove the `:focus` selector.

However I'd like to know why this happens and are there any other css rules or situations where this can occur.

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug on Bugzilla? I can help you to that, if you want.

Comment: Yes, submitted, thanks for the offer. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186140

Comment: why don't you try the onfocus event on textarea, which is more logical to use in your case?

Comment: What's the question? How Firefox bugs work? I'm afraid nobody knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does look like a bug (thanks for filing it!), generally a click event is dispatched to the deepest element that observed both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. So you can similarly "break" the click event by moving the textarea on `:focus` (e.g. `position:absolute; top: xxx`) - this is because the order of events is mousedown->focus (updates the web page)->mouseup->click.

The `resize` property [controls "anonymous content"](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/325c1a707819602feff736f129cb36055ba6d94f/layout/generic/nsGfxScrollFrame.cpp#4867) that's not visible to the web page, but used by the browser to implement the additional UI for the user's benefit. My guess is that changes to this content interfere with [`click` event detection](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/325c1a707819602feff736f129cb36055ba6d94f/dom/events/EventStateManager.cpp#4929), but without looking at this in a debug build it's impossible to say for sure.

```js
function logEvent(ev) {console.log(ev.type, window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("textarea")).resize)}

document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("mousedown", logEvent, false);
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("focus", logEvent, false);
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("mouseup", logEvent, false);
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("click", logEvent, true);
```

```css
textarea:focus{
  position:absolute; top: 500px;
  /*resize:vertical;*/
}
```

```html
<textarea>click me</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you click on the resize button, you don't focus to the textarea but to the **resize button** on Firefox. I do not know if this is a bug or not, but it looks like it was intended. Removing `:focus` removes the requirement of focusing on the textarea, therefore it applies when you hold the resize button, which only goes vertically.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to use jQuery focus. For me it is more simple yet effective and applicable to all kind of browsers.

If you want it focus upon loading the page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#txtId').focus();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and explain a bit in how far it solves the problem, what your solution does, ... For more guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer